# Which verb fits better for the action of "creating" an earth connection?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, technical

The following sentence is used on a warning label:

> Ensure that an earth connection is made

I think that "making an earth connection" doesn't express the real intent here. The alternatives that I can think of are:

> provided
>
> created (not so suitable)
>
> connected ("connection is connected" sounds a little bit off)
>
> done (very unlikely)

Any other suggestions?

Comment: In what way do you think the original misses the intent?

Comment: "the front metal panels must be soundly **earthed**"

Comment: Electrical connections are generally *made*, so I think any other verb would be worse. However, the whole sentence sounds rather unidiomatic to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "making an earth connection", try

**Earth** as a verb. — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/earth)

> *British* Connect (an electrical device) with the ground
>
> *"the front metal panels must be soundly earthed"*
> *"When plugged in, the pump is earthed and I have a little more piece of mind!"*
> *"They are not able to be earthed, filtered, or shielded electrically."*

**Ground** as a verb. — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/ground)

> *North American* Connect (an electrical device) with the ground.
>
> *"The spark plugs must be grounded to complete the electrical circuit."*